# How do I get a Winbond Wireless Card to work?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, ndiswrapper

I own a technology blog and I received a question via e-mail asking how to get a Winbond wireless card to work on Linux (preferably Ubuntu). I don't personally have any experience getting Winbond cards up and running on Linux and a search of the internet didn't seem to turn up any results.

Apparently ndiswrapper fails to detect the card as well. If anyone could provide some assistance in getting an internal, Winbond networking card working with Linux I would be most appreciative.

Comment: I don't suppose the person left more detail? "Winbond" returns all sorts of different results in google so it's tough to find out which specific issue he could be having.

Comment: chipset would be helpful but all I found at the moment was `Winbond W89C35` and `w89c840`. Assuming it is... see my answer.

Comment: I am awaiting reply on the chipset version...

Comment: The exact version is: Winbond W89C33 mPCI 802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter. Any idea if the below directions for ndiswrapper will work for this model? I unfortunately don't have access to one of these cards to test it myself.

Answer (score 1):

As of Ubuntu Lucid Lynx it seems it *should* work with ndiswrapper. This is the driver you need for it to work in ndiswrapper: [Winbond W89C35 driver](http://drop.fakap.net/files/IS89C35.zip)  (vid:0416 pid:0035). Just follow the [Ubuntu ndiswrapper wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) ([Source](http://blog.mypapit.net/2010/07/winbond-w89c35-vid0416-pid0035-usb-wireless-driver.html)).

Besides that there is [nictools-pci](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nictools-pci) [image: Install nictools-pci] for some diagnostics.

"These tools can help you to diagnose problems with your ethernet cards
or - in some cases - give those cards the final hint, to work in your
network." 
It includes: `winbond-diag`  Diagnostic and setup for the `Winbond w89c840` Ethernet cards.